# sphinx search with date

Tags: sphinx

I am creating index on sphinx compatible xml data.

In my file i have tag of date for which i define type as timestamp.
Data for that tag is like below

> "Thu, 7 Jun 2012 00:00:00 PDT".

I have define tag as

```
<sphinx:attr type="timestamp" name="rss.channel.item.pubDate"/>
```

in my Sphinx compatible xml document.
Problem is,when i try to search using this data it does not give me any index related to it.
So how can i index and search for date in sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

Its expected to be a numeric timestamp, rather than a string

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-xmlpipe-attr-timestamp

you will have to convert it first.